# DataFrame for large datasets in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataframe, time-series

I’m looking for advice on dealing with large datasets in C#. In R I have been using data.table which is fine for performing joins on tables in excess of 100m rows and would need to be performing time-series based calculations alongside slice and dice operations. However the core modelling framework needs to be in C#.

In C# I have encountered Deedle which is fine for smaller datasets but would not possibly manage the required size.

I have also found the licensed solution from Extreme Optimisation which seems to have potential.

Are there other possibilities that may work? I wish to stay within the .Net framework and do not wish to perform cross language (C# to R or Python) interactions as this would likely be poor performing, especially when getting into simulation work requiring the transition of large amounts of data across boundaries. C# is also preferred to Python due to the fit with other architecture (web services, UI etc) throughout the company.

Comment: I would use SQL Server for database.  You can either use a SQL Server with database a MDF file attached to the server, or use a local database queries a MDF file not attached to the server.  Using a server will be faster.  There are a few libraries in Net which work with the SQL Server like SQLClient or Entity.

Comment: That’s not really a viable option. We’re talking about mathematical modelling and analysis. SQL isn’t comparable to what R’s data.table or Pandas’ dataframe can achieve or how they can be used.

Comment: The database is only for storage for data and not the processing.  Do you need real time processing of the data or can it be done offline?  Can you use Matlab for processing?  You can create a dll for matlab code that can be called from c#.

Comment: Matlab is unsuitable as I’m then crossing language boundaries. I can currently use Python with pandas or R with data.table to handle large datasets (100+m rows), what I’m looking for is a C# solution. This is about computation and numerical analysis, the data does not require database storage as it is simulated using random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft started implementing a DataFrame in .net

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.cs

Its part of ML.net

I currently also deal with larger data in C# that I need to transfer to python and back and I would recommend to avoid it if it can be done.